# Do I have to end with "Finally" in the sentence pattern "First, Second, Third, and Finally"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I end with "Thirdly" to end instead of "Finally" (say I do not have the 4th point), is this wrong or inappropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason you have to use "Finally"; "Thirdly" is acceptable for the last item in a three-item list. In fact, I think I'd actually *prefer* to stick with the numbering unless the list has at least four or five items.

However, I would keep the usage consistent. So "Firstly", "Secondly", and "Thirdly is fine; as is "First", "Second", and "Third". But I would avoid mixing them. So I'd avoid,"First", "Second", and "Thirdly".

All that said, I tend to avoid the "-ly" forms altogether. I prefer "First", "Second" "Third" etc; over "Firstly", "Secondly", "Thirdly" etc. But these days, that's more a question of style and personal preference than of grammatical correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Why should it be wrong or inappropriate? If it is the third thing in the list, you can begin with *Thirdly*.